# T.A springer lemma on dominant morphisms between irreducible varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to understand the following lemma in T.A springer's linear algebraic groups.

[image]

My problem is with understanding the last sentence shown above.

Firstly why should the fact that the ideal in the above argument goes to zero imply that the algebra of regular functions on the fiber is K[T]?
Is it because the kernel of the map in question is the ideal of regular functions vanishing on the fiber? If so how do we know the function b does not vanish on the fiber as well?

secondly why should the isomorphism of said algebra to K[T] imply the fiber is isomorphic to the affine line? shouldn't this line of reasoning only apply in the case of an affine variety?

Answer (score 1):

OK, first of all there must be some missing ambient assumptions. Are $X$ and $Y$ assumed to be reduced? For example, the map $\mathrm{Spec}(k)\to\mathrm{Spec}(k[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2))$ is dominant (it's a homeomorphism) map of irreducible varieties but certainly $k[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2)$ does not embed into $k$ as $k$-algebras. So, let's assume that everything is reduced. Then, it is true that the induced map
$$A:=k[Y]\to k[X]=:B$$
is injective.

If we now assume that $B=A[b]$ then note that for any prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$ one has that

$$\begin{aligned}\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}) &=\mathrm{Spec}(B\otimes_A k(\mathfrak{p}))\\ &= \mathrm{Spec}(A[b]\otimes_A k(\mathfrak{p}))\\ &= \mathrm{Spec}(k(\mathfrak{p})[T]/\overline{I_b})\end{aligned}$$

where $k(\mathfrak{p}):=A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$ is the residue field of $A$ at $\mathfrak{p}$, $I_b$ is the kernel of the $A$-algebra map $A[t]\to B$ given by $t\mapsto b$, and $\overline{I_b}$ is the image of $I_b$ under the quotient map $A[t]\to k(\mathfrak{p})[T]$.

From this we see that there is a closed embedding

$$\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})\hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^1_{k(\mathfrak{p})}$$

which clearly implies, thinking about the closed subschemes of $\mathbb{A}^1_{k(\mathfrak{p})}$, that $\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$ is either finite or isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1_{k(\mathfrak{p})}$.

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed answer.

Comment: unfortunately I did not understand the part in the middle regarding the computation of the fiber algebra....my understanding of algebraic geometry is quite limited and I am not yet familiar with the language of schemes. if you could provide a more elementary explanation more inline with the language of the first chapter of Hartshorne it would be great.

Comment: Like the statement that $B=A[b]$ means that there is a surjective map $A[T]\to B$ which means that $X$ is a closed subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^1_A=Y\times_k \mathbb{A}^1_k$. So then, the fiber of a point $p$ of $Y$ of the map $X\to Y$ is going to be a closed subvariety of the fiber over $p$ of the map $Y\times_k \mathbb{A}^1_k\to Y$. But, this is clearly just a subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^1_{k(p)}$ (where $k(p)$ is the residue field at $p$--it's just $k$ if you're working in the algebraically closed situation and $p$ is a closed point, which is the situation of Harsthorne chapter 1).

Comment: thank you. I think I understand now.